# How can I uninstall IPFS completely and restart everything from scratch and get a new peer id?

Tags: ipfs

How can I uninstall IPFS completely and restart everything from scratch and get a new peer id? I tried to delete the go-ipfs folder but I can still get Error: ipfs configuration file already exists! when I do ipfs init.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data store as well as the config will be stored in a subdirectory `.ipfs` of your home directory. So if you are on a UNIX based system `$HOME/.ipfs`. You would have to delete this directory and then run `ipfs init` to get an empty store and a new peer id.

Note that you can also configure the location of the store directory using the IPFS_PATH environment variable, which can be useful to get the IPFS store on a different mount point.